# Virtualbox - Two different screen orientations for Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu (15.04) VM running on a Windows 8.1 host in a two monitor configuration. At times, when I'm reading a lot of documents, I like to rotate one of the screens to be in portrait mode to make it easier to see the full document all at once. When I try to do this with the Ubuntu VM, things go funky. I do it by first rotating the screen in the host OS, then turning on the VM in full screen.

[image: Desired screen orientation]

When the VM is in full screen mode, things look good at first. On the login screen, the screens are properly oriented, and utilize the full resolution of the monitors. After I log in, however, it all goes bad. The landscape-oriented monitor looks fine and is full screen, but the portrait-oriented screen switches back to landscape, leaving big black bars at the top and bottom, and only half of the screen showing on the display.

[image: Actual screen orientation]

I've tried looking at the display settings in Ubuntu, but there is no option to rotate the screen. I also tried using `xrandr` to rotate the screen, but that also did not work, telling me that the option to rotate the screen is unavailable.